# Geometrical construction with means of elementary geometry

Tags: geometry

Consider the setup in the figure attached to this post, where we are given a triangle (no special one) and around each corner a circle of radius $r_i$ (possibly different). Moreover, consider the circle intersecting those three circles at a *right angle* (dashed line, right angles marked by points). The distance from the midpoint of that circle to side $i$ is denoted by $h_i$, the length of side $i$ by $l_i$ and the angle at corner $i$ by $\theta_i$.

Suppose we know $r_i,\theta_i,l_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ and want to find out $h_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Is there a suggestion how to relate the knowns to the unknowns?

[image: Figure]